# docker file storage path modification related questions

Tags: docker-desktop

I want to modify the image file storage path of Docker Desktop, but when I click Apply&reset, I keep staying in the loading interface. Is there any solution?
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da9T9.png)

I have tried to reinstall Docker Desktop, but still can't solve the problem.